# Need help without sorting some data

Tags: sas, teradata

I have a problem converting a SAS code to SQL. There's a line of code that involves sorting some rows of a table from SAS that I can't seem to replicate to SQL.

I have tried using different types of row_number by partition clauses and even tried ordering the rows using a unique identifier, but I always obtain different results than the SAS code.

```
data Testing;                                           
input col1$ col2$ col3$ col4$ col5$ col6$ col7$ new;       
datalines;                       
7.3 11 11 A AAB 1245 20 1               
7.3 11 11 A AAB 1245 20 32             
;

proc sort data = Testing nodupkey;
by col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6;
```

For the SAS code above, my results were the following row:

```
7.3 11 11 A AAB 1245 20 1
```

which is the 1st row on the Testing table.

However, if I tried to use any code involving row numbers and partitions in Teradata, I always obtain the 2nd row instead:

```
7.3 11 11 A AAB 1245 20 32
```

From what I understand, SQL should not does store rows in any particular order, while SAS does. I'm trying to find a way to replicate this SAS ordering procedure in SQL, but I always get different results.

If it helps, I'm currently running this SQL query:

```
select * from Testing                 
qualify row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 order by col1 asc, col2 asc, col3 asc, col4 asc, col5 asc, col6 asc)=1
```

I tried using either asc or desc for the order by part, but in either case, I obtain the 2nd row and not the 1st.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's because your data has ties and it's ambiguous as to which row should be taken. Is there any step prior to that involves the value new that may indicate which should be taken in the case of ties.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. As I mentioned below, adding a unique identifier doesn't always work. The weird part is that despite Teradata supposedly being ambigious in terms of row orders, for some reason I always end up getting the 2nd row when I use a row number over partition clause. I'm trying to figure out why that is. Also, if it helps, do you know if there's any sort of SQL equivalent to the nodupkeys from the SAS query above? Thanks for helping!

Comment: If you can tell the difference between which row is coming first then there must be additional variables you can add to the sort key to generate the a unique order.  But that would require change both TD and SAS code.  At worst case sort on every column.

Comment: What's the Primary Index of the Teradata table?

Comment: Thanks Tom and dnoeth. I'll try sorting using some other columns. Its worth noting that if I export this data to a spreadsheet, add an identity column on it, and then import it back to Teradata, I will get the right results. Only problem is that I'm pretty sure I was requested to this do using solely Teradata and not any other sources. By the way, the primary index is col1.

Comment: Have you considered that the original query may not have cared which was chosen?  Why is the first row correct as opposed to the second?

Comment: The 1st row was chosen by SAS because it came 1st in the list. I don't know how this will be used because it wasn't discussed with me, but I do need to replicate the SAS query exactly, which includes choosing theses 1st values from the "new" column. There's more to it, of course, but I pretty much have everything else aside from this step. What might help is if I can figure out how a table is sorted when you use proc SQL. The list from here was actually a result of a proc SQL code that selected thousands of rows from various tables.

Comment: How do you know that the 1st row is correct? If your answer is *it's based on the order of rows in the input file* then find out how this file was created and repeat the sorting logic found there. How do you import this file into Teradata? If it's based on *FastLoad/TPT Load* or *BTEQ/TPT Inserter* you might add an IDENDITY column to the table and use a single session for your import. Finally order by this sequence in your Row_Number.

Comment: Yes, the answer is based on the rows in the input file. The input file was created from a proc SQL code that pulled the data from various tables from Teradata. I can use that same proc SQL code in both SAS and Teradata, but like you said the SAS code saves the result as an input file and therefore has an order to the rows, while Teradata just stored them randomly. I'm currently trying to find what this order is, but there doesn't seem like there's any. Is there an order that comes from using a proc SQL code?

Comment: If the input file is created from a Select against Teradata (or any other DBMS) tables and there's no Order By in the Select the "1st" row is completely random. You might simply add (or extend the existing) Order By to this Select to get a unique/repeatable order.

Answer (score 1):

When `PROC SORT` is used with the `NODUPKEY` option, it keeps the first record it encounters in the input dataset. This behavior is controlled by the `EQUALS / NOEQUALS` option.

According to the documentation "EQUALS is the default. For observations that have identical BY-variable values, EQUALS maintains the order from the input data set in the output data set. NOEQUALS does not necessarily preserve this order in the output data set. NOEQUALS can save CPU time and memory resources."

I am not an expert in TD, but from what I know, as you stated correctly, Terradata does not have a notion of row number and hence a default order.  The code you are using just assigns a row_number on the fly on the results, rather than the actual underlying data - this will lead to different assignments on each attempts to pull the same records.

I assume you are trying to validate your code by getting identical results in SAS and SQL in TD. If you truly want identical results, I suggest you create an unique identifier in TD, re-extract from it to re-create a SAS dataset and then use that ID as part of sorting etc. Or you may have to rely on the ordering of other columns to get the same records out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to replicate the results of the SAS query to SQL, so I want a SQL query that will take the 1st row instead of the 2nd. I can't change the SAS query in any way, so I'll have to leave it as is. The table shown here is actually just a part of a much larger table. I have tried creating a unique identifier on that larger table, but due to Teradata not ordering the rows in any unique way, this causes the SQL query to produce slightly different results everytime its run.

Comment: In fact Teradata has a ROWID which can be used to order rows according to the time of Insert (sequentially increasing for all rows with the same Primary Index value), but using it in SQL is disabled in most systems.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks for that info. I am not a DB person, but our engineers have always asked us to manually create unique IDs in our solution. Probably there is a good reason why it is disabled / not used widely?

Comment: The main reason: It was abused by users coming from Oracle for access (in Where-conditions) despite TD clearly stating that it's informational only. Access was made really slow, i.e. a Full Table Scan, but they still used it. When the RowId format changed (4 -> 6 bytes) users started complaining about failing applications and it was switched off :-)

Comment: The rowid you mentioned here is probably what I'm looking for. Is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL language only guarantees ordering of rows when you use the ORDER BY clause in your query.  Different implementations (or different optimization in the same implementation) might generate different orders when multiple observations fall into the same ORDER BY group.

SAS stores data in physical files that have defined order of the observations.  So its implementation will in general return observations for the same group in the order they originally had in the dataset.  Teradata does not have a similar concept.  It stores and analyzes data in parallel.  Any given run will return rows in the order that the different processors happen to finish generating them.

So you need to have one (or more) variables that you can use to re-create the order.

You could add the variable to your SAS dataset and re-load that into Teradata.  For example a simple step like this will make a unique ROWID value for each observation.

```
 data want;
    rowid + 1;
    set have;
 run;
```

Then you could use ROWID in your ROW_NUMBER() function call.

```
select * 
  from Testing_with_rowid
  qualify 1=row_number() over 
    (partition by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 
     order by rowid)
  order by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 
;
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I understand what you're saying, but I don't think I'm allowed to edit the SAS code. Also, I'm simplifying it here, but the original table actually came from running a proc SQL query on SAS, so I don't know if I can just add a unique identifier.  Is there any sort of order for the rows of a table in SAS when using a proc SQL code? Or is it just random?

Comment: PROC SQL also generally returns results in the order they originally had (probably calling the same underlying logic), but you can't count on it.  If you include every selected variable in the ORDER BY clause then the order is determined.

Comment: By including every selected variable in the order by clause, do you mean including every column used in the proc SQL code into the qualify partition row number code you wrote above? Meaning instead of rowid, I would use every column used in the proc SQL code? Also, the proc SQL code was used to pull data from tables in Teradata, so would that have any effect on the ordering of the table in SAS?

Comment: Yes.  If you have 10 columns, 4 of which are your normal grouping/ordering variables then sort by all 10 columns.  If you pull the data from TD into SAS then it should normally be stored in the order that TD delivered it to SAS. Again use an ORDER BY to explicitly tell TD what order to deliver the data.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more question, since the SAS code involves only using the 6 columns from above in the nodupkey part, they should be the only columns used in the partition by part, correct? So it should be partition by the 6 columns followed by order by all the columns from the proc SQL query.

Comment: If you are ordering by all of the columns then how can there be a difference between which duplicate is selected?

Comment: Didn't you say I should sort by all the columns or maybe I misunderstood? What I'm thinking right now is to use the following SQL code in place of the nodupkeys SAS code:                                                                       qualify row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col5 order by all the rows from the proc SQL code)=1

Comment: If your output only has the 5 key columns then there is no need to worry about which observation you take when there are duplicate keys since that means you have exact duplicates.  But if your output has MORE than those 5 columns then there can be differences between observations with the same keys. In that case ordering by all of the variables will make the choice non-random. So in your TD SQL OVER clause PARTITION BY the key variables and ORDER BY all of the other non-key variables.